# How to set state's keys from a function's parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```js
const getElementDims = (node, id) => {
    this.setState(
        taskDims[id] = node.getBoundingClientRect()
    )
}
```

I know that this code is not working, but i really don't have any idea how to solve this problem. I want to set the state's `taskDims` object's key as the id get from the function, and set the node's parameters to it. The problem is with the key. How can i set it? Will converting it into an array, and set the array's elements as an object, and setting a key-value pair of the id be a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a copy of the `taskDims` object and overwrite the value with the key `id`:

```
const getElementDims = (node, id) => {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const taskDims = {...previousState.taskDims};
    taskDims[id] = node.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { taskDims };
  });
}
```

Comment: Since it depends on previous state, might consider using callback `setState` instead, but this will probably work fine